# JasperReports Library used in Java Code and Exporting to PDF generates Exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, export-to-pdf

I am working on a web application and using *JasperReports* library (jasperreports-4.8.0.jar). In the application, I have a function to export some generated data (from a database) into PDF format. In particular,

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport()
```

function is called. As I got to know, the *ОК* library internally uses *iText* for its PDF generation. I also have itext-2.1.7.jar in my classpath, which I hope is used in the PDF generation.

The trace of exception I get is (partially):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.checkGlyphComposite(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.flatGlyphs(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontSubSet.process(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.TrueTypeFontUnicode.writeFont(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.FontDetails.writeFont(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSharedObjectsToBody(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:707)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:396)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:212)
[10/21/14 19:13:09:366 SGT] 00000030 SystemErr     R    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:536)
```

My question: How to get rid of this error? What's causing this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ? 
Note: The jasper report (original file: report.jrxml) compiles successfully (compiled file: report.jasper) in *iReport* ver. 4.8.0, meaning the report query is also valid and ok.

PS: I have tried variations of itext-2.1.5, jasperreports-5.6.1 libraries. However they seem to be not solving the problem.

Comment: Try changing the font or your jdk.

Comment: Changing the font worked fine in iReport only. Still the exception is there when executing the report. The report is deployed into  WebSphere under a path under: install\resource\report.

Comment: Might need to check into its original source, I checked it was at `document.close()` for the version of 4.8.0 but not so clear of the reason.

Related to font, from my experience, you need to use any font that exists in Java of your server or you may check in `/jre/lib/fonts`